# Assigning a variable to a spreadsheet open by a third party software

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-instances

I am running into issue pulling data from a workbook that is open via SAP. The macro runs and executes multiple things in SAP and then opens the required data. The data is opened by opening an Excel window. What I am currently doing, is I assign a variable for that workbook. And use that reference throughout the entire macro.

```
Dim SAP_WB as workbook
'macro works within SAP and results in a workbook that pops up on the screen    
Set SAP_WB=ActiveWorkbook
'macro manipulates the opened workbook and gets specific data.
```

That workbook is assigned to the first excel instance. The macro works great if the user has the excel tool with macros opened on the first instance as well. But if the user has multiple instances open, that is when the ActiveWorkbook does not apply. The workbook that is open from SAP has a dynamic name that I have no control over. Is there anyway to assign a variable to that workbook even though it is on another instance?

Comment: This kind of has me stumped... Perhaps you can add an inputbox if excel has > 1 workbooks open that prompts the user to add the workbook name manually? Then you could use that variable like so: `Set SAP_WB=ActiveWorkbook(MyVariable)`

Comment: This is a tool that used across a wide range of users. Not all of them are familiar with excel instances. And I really do not want to ask them close the workbook and open it in the main(first) instance. Was hoping to deal with it through the macro and avoid interacting with end-user.

Comment: @M.Marzouk I recommend opening the WB read only and then assigning it to the WB object. `Set SAP_WB=Application.WorkBooks.Open("C:\MyWB.xlsx",ReadOnly:=True)`

Comment: That is not possible. I am controlling SAP in background. And the only option in SAP is a button that opens it in excel right away. There is no option to save the file. Once the button is clicked, that workbook is popped open on the screen. There is no other options.

Comment: No one has a solution for this???? :(